# Use inland or foreign

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If we want to let the world know about our country, Shall we say  "To improve foreign trips" or "To improve inland trips"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend either. I would say "to improve tourism".

Comment: I wouldn't use any of them too, but unfortunately it is a "choose" question in an English exam.

Comment: Is that the entire text if the question? Is there any more context you can provide? If that's all the question asks, it would be safest to choose "foreign", with my reminder that in "real life" this is not how the word would be used.

Comment: It's just like that "We should encourage (inland - foreign) trips to enable people to know more about our country. "

Comment: Then *foreign*, because typically the people who know least about your country are *foreigners*. The only case where you'd use *inland* trips is when people you are trying to educate about your country are natives who mostly live and remain on the coast, and you want to encourage them to visit the relatively unpopulous areas *inland*.

Answer (score 1):

*Inland trips* means trips to the part of the country away from the coast, without specifying who is taking those trips. Such trips may let the world know about your country, or they may not.

*Foreign trips*. on the other hand, is fatally ambiguous. It can mean, and has been taken by others here to mean, trips by foreigners to your country, which would be what is asked for. But technically, a *foreign trip* is just a trip to a foreign country and the trip-takers should be presumed to be your fellow-countrymen; if they travel abroad, that would give them information about the world, not the other way about.

So the choice is between a bad answer and a very bad answer. I would say *inland* is less bad, but if the examiner thinks one choice is correct, you need to know how he thinks, not how the English language works.

Answer (score 0):

> - **"inland"** - (adj) of, relating to, or in the part of a country that is away from the coast or boundaries. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inland)

If you want to increase tourism in your country, you might say:

- "If we improve road conditions, **inland tourism** will certainly increase."
- "If we improve our airport conditions, the influx of **foreign tourists** will be greater."
- "An advertising campaign on international TV channels would certainly bring more tourists."

postscript - Instead of "to improve inland trips" I would say "If we improve road conditions (or tourism infrastructure as a whole), **we will be encouraging inland tourism**. "To improve foreign trips" sounds awkward in this context.

Comment: Exactly. And so does "improve inland trips". If the object is to improve tourist (revenue), the direct way is to "encourage" trips to your country by foreign tourists, whether the trips are "inland" or not.  I think the teacher might have confused "inland" with "inbound" and "improve" with "increase", making for a very badly worded test question. I would argue that that question should not be counted in scoring the test.